# Xcode: Use Imagemagick to create AppIcons during building time

Tags: ios, xcode, imagemagick

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/1716-how-to-change-your-app-icon-at-build-time) to modify AppIcons according to the configuration (debug/staging/distribution) during the building phases.

I created the following run script:

```
IFS=$'\n'
buildNumber=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleVersion" "${PROJECT_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_FILE}")
versionNumber=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleShortVersionString" "${PROJECT_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_FILE}")
PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/bin

function generateIcon () {
    BASE_IMAGE_NAME=$1
    
    TARGET_PATH="${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}/${BASE_IMAGE_NAME}"
    echo $TARGET_PATH
    #echo $SRCROOT
    #echo $(find ${SRCROOT} -name "Icon-iPhone-60@3x.png")
    BASE_IMAGE_PATH=$(find ${SRCROOT} -name ${BASE_IMAGE_NAME})
    WIDTH=$(identify -format %w ${BASE_IMAGE_PATH})
    
    if [ "${CONFIGURATION}" == "EnterpriseStaging" ]; then
    convert StagingRibbon.png -resize ${WIDTH}x${WIDTH} resizedRibbon.png
    composite resizedRibbon.png - ${TARGET_PATH}
    fi
    
    if [ "${CONFIGURATION}" == "EnterpriseProduction" ]; then
    convert ProdRibbon.png -resize ${WIDTH}x${WIDTH} resizedRibbon.png
    composite resizedRibbon.png - ${TARGET_PATH}
    fi
}

generateIcon "Icon-iPhone-60@3x.png"
generateIcon "Icon-iPhone-60@2x.png"
generateIcon "Icon-iPhone-40@3x.png"
generateIcon "Icon-iPhone-40@2x.png"
generateIcon "Icon-iPhone-29@3x.png"
generateIcon "Icon-iPhone-29@2x.png"
generateIcon "Icon-iPhone-20@3x.png"
generateIcon "Icon-iPhone-20@2x.png"
```

**This is the console output.**

> composite: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/554.
>
> composite:  `/Users/moraleda/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CLCarRental-exspsgiumroqxzgzgtpmazepfnvy/Build/Products/EnterpriseStaging-iphonesimulator/CLCarRental.app/Icon-iPhone-60@3x.png' @ error/composite.c/CompositeImageCommand/1627.

I tested the commands with images on my desktop and they worked just fine. I assume there is a problem accessing the simulator folder, but I cannot really figure it out...

Comment: Just a quick guess... I would assume you want to run this script first, output the generated images into your project / assets folder structure, and then let the build process use those images (as opposed to trying to stuff them into the build folder).

Comment: Is the extra `-` following `composite resizedRibbon.png` statement a typo? The composite utility seems to be expecting an additional image.

Comment: The `-` is required. @DonMag I'm changing the strategy and creating the icons before buidling, but according to the tutorial in RW it should work this way as well...

Comment: Reread step 4 in the tutorial. The `-` symbol tells the composite utility to read from STDIN. In the script above, I'm not seeing any data written to STDIN.